# Вызов функции onClick JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется ***2*** таблицы ***3 х 3***. При клике на какой-либо элемент во второй таблице, он становится прозрачным. Помогите написать функцию, которая при нажатии ячейки в первой таблице делает непрозрачным аналогичный элемент из другой таблицы

> P.s все элементы во второй таблице присвоены одному классу
>
> P.s. Если не сложно, объясните, пожалуйста, как это будет работать,
>   или скиньте ссылку, где об этом можно досконально почитать.

Заранее спасибо!

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="secondTable.style.opacity='1';"> 1 </td>
    <td onClick="secondTable.style.opacity='1';"> 2 </td>
    <td onClick="secondTable.style.opacity='1';"> 3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="secondTable">1</td>
    <td class="secondTable">2</td>
    <td class="secondTable">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Код покажите свой: сделайте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 2):

Нужно задать аналогичным элементам двух таблиц одинаковые классы (я задал .one, .two, .three) и при клике на элемент из первой таблицы проверять, есть ли такой класс у элемента второй таблицы, и делать его непрозрачным:

```js
$('.secondTable').click(function(){
  $(this).css('opacity', '0')
})

$('.firstTable').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('one')) {
    $('.secondTable.one').css('opacity', '1');
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('two')) {
    $('.secondTable.two').css('opacity', '1');
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('three')) {
    $('.secondTable.three').css('opacity', '1');
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border :1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="firstTable one">1</td>
    <td class="firstTable two">2</td>
    <td class="firstTable three">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="secondTable one">1</td>
    <td class="secondTable two">2</td>
    <td class="secondTable three">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал бы так:

```js
document.getElementById('t2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('transparent');
  }
});

document.getElementById('t1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    let r = e.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
    let c = e.target.cellIndex;

    document.getElementById('t2').rows[r].cells[c].classList.remove('transparent');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<table id="t2">
  <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
</table>
```